# Role based authorization with cancan doesn't works Rails 4 - Ruby 2.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I use cancan (1.6.10) and devise (3.2.2), I have been implementing authorization using [this guide](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization#wiki-many-roles-per-user) as recommended by cancan's author, I need to assign multiple roles to a user then I decided store it into a single integer column using a bitmask (I added a column named "roles_mask" to user model).

I have this files involved:

1. [user.rb](https://gist.github.com/geoom/9340643)
2. [edit.html.erb](https://gist.github.com/geoom/9340635)

I'm aware that I folowed word by word of this guide except the lines that I wrote for indicate that roles is a accessible attribute:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :roles) }
  end
end
```

When update a user (logged), all fields are updated except :roles_mask =/, I don't understand why roles field is not captured. I think there's something that I don't achieve to see. anyone can help me?

***Solution**:

Using [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) (support for Rails 4) and change application_controller.rb file it works (as roles is a non-scalar attribute).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, roles: []) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CanCan does not support Rails 4. You can however use CanCanCan, which is Rails4 friendly: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I didn't notice that detail ... I'll try and tell you later.

Comment: well ... @rails4guides.com, it seems that the issue persist in that gem, I just report to cancancan comunity (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/11) .. some idea ?

Comment: Try to define your roles within the strong parameters as an array: roles: []

Comment: that's works ... thank u very much @rails4guides.com , btw it would be helpful if it were in docs, I going to describe the illustrates solution in my question.