# before_action for standard/admin users : how to give admin the rights of all other users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'd like to give some more rights to my admin users that the regular users, here are my before_action :

```
# users_controller.rb
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
before_action :admin_user, only: [:destroy, :index, :admin_toggle]
```

So if you're the correct user, you can : edit, update, show your own profile.

If you're an admin_user, you can see the list (index), destroy your own profile, toggle admin any user, edit/update/show your own profile (admin_user is also a correct_user).

I'd like an admin_user to be able to edit, update, show others members profiles : do I need to write specific methods or is there a trick with before_action to do ?

It seems to be like admin_user should have the rights of correct_user -with any user ID given-.

Comment: I get the feeling you're conflating what purpose `before_action` really should be having here.  It's intended to invoke a method, not really regulate access to resources; that should be controlled by other business logic that's not *necessarily* here.

Comment: Thanks for that. After reading you I've searched the web about admin interfaces with Rails and, indeed, there are tools that are way more coherent !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use somekind of specific authentication tools like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for ex. then I suggest implementing authorization solution with 
[cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem. You have a specific ability file there under your models directory where you can declare access-rights for different user roles.

Makes your future code much cleaner and easier to read also.

**###EDIT:**

As previous answer points out then there is also a [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem but as much as I know then it is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22164325/1677069) in Rails4. While writing this answer, CanCanCan build-status in github is marked as `failing` but I've been using it for a long time now in my projects and I'm happy :)

**###**

`ability.rb` example:

```
def secretary_abilities
  can [:create, :read, :update], Person
end

def superadmin_abilities
  # superadmin can do everything that secretary can
  secretary_abilities
  # ...and can also do destructive actions
  can [:destroy], Person
end
```

After that you can add checks into your views like this:

```
<% if can? :show, Person %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', person_path(@person) %>
<% end %>
```